# Why asp.net button is not hiding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am facing a weird problem in asp.net forms. I am trying to make button invisible/Inactive but none of my code works in any situation. It remains visible/active.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrintEditedSms" ValidationGroup="Complaints"  runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success"  
            OnClick="btnPrintEditedSms_Click" Text="Send" />
```

I am trying to put code here, to make it visible or inactive but not doesn't work although other statements work

```
 protected void GridViewAllSms_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BtnPrintEditedSms.Visible = false; //this doesn't work
        BtnPrintEditedSms.Enabled = false; //this also
        txtComplainant.Visible = true;     //this works

    }
```

It is within Update Panel:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updGridViewSMS" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
          <ContentTemplate>
            <label><b>Search By Date Range</b></label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDateFrom" runat="server" Text="From"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>                      
            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderFromDate" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtFromDate" runat="server">
            </asp:CalendarExtender>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtFromDate" Display="None" ErrorMessage="" 
                                ForeColor="Red" >
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDateTo" runat="server" Text="To"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderToDate" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtToDate" runat="server">
            </asp:CalendarExtender>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtToDate" Display="None" ErrorMessage="" 
                                ForeColor="Red" >
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearchByDate"  CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text="Search" 
                        ClientIDMode="Static"  OnClick="btnSearchByDate_Click" />
            &nbsp; 
            <asp:Button ID="btnEdit"  CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text="Edit" 
                        ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnEdit_Click"  />
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Your button ID is `btnSend`, not `BtnPrintEditedSms`?

Comment: which button you want to hide?

Comment: if you mistakenly put btnSend here then check is your button is in UpdatePanel?

Comment: @DavidG check updated code, doesn't work either

Comment: @V2Solutions-MSTeam yes within update button

Comment: @JohnNash No, is it in an `UpdatePanel` for doing Ajax type stuff?

Comment: if update mode is coditional then in GridViewAllSms_SelectedIndexChanged event you need to update your UpdatePanel manually like updatepanelname.Update();

Comment: yes yes, it is within update panel, content tag

Comment: Can you post the code for the panel too then?

Comment: You have still a spelling error in your code above. They have to be completely identical, so switch the ID to: `ID="BtnPrintEditedSms"`. In your CodeBehind you spell it `BtnPrintEditedSms` but in the aspx-page you spell it at the moment `btnPrintEditedSms`

Comment: @DatRid: i have corrected them but still doesn't work and it was type while pasting in here nto in actual code

Comment: @V2Solutions-MSTeam tried ur solution but no effect

Comment: So the grid (`GridViewAllSms`) is not in the update panel, or in another panel?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 protected void GridViewAllSms_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BtnPrintEditedSms.Visible = false; //this doesn't work
        BtnPrintEditedSms.Enabled = false; //this also
        txtComplainant.Visible = true;     //this works
        Updatepanel1.Update();
    }
```

or if you dont want to set your update mode set to conditional then set it to always like

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Updatepanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
```